# Are node.js event's handlers executed when the calling stack is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used to think that code related to node.js events are asynchronous. But the following example doesn't stick to that :

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on('foo', function () {
    console.log('Foo handler');
});
emitter.emit('foo');

console.log('Synchronous code!');
```

The 'foo' event should be added to the eventQueue and processed after the main function. But 'Synchronous Code' is displayed before 'Foo handler'. Why?

Do the events raised by emitter.emit() gets pushed to the eventsQueue in node ? If no, which ones do ?

Answer (score 0):

Cause the Event Loop.

`emitter.on` and `emitter.emit` will be scheduled after this context execution.

like you're doing:

```
setImmediate(() => console.log('after Sync code in this context'))
console.log('Synchronous code!')
```

Another example

```
'use strict'

// handlers are executed in the order in which they are registered

console.log('Expected order: 1 2 a c b')

process.on('asd', () => console.log('a'))

function test () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.on('asd', () => console.log('b'))
  }, 100)

  process.on('asd', () => console.log('c'))

  setTimeout(() => {
    process.emit('asd')
  }, 200)

  console.log('2')
}

console.log('1')

test()
```

Comment: `setImmediate()` calls the callback at the end of this turn of the Node.js Event Loop. But what i am saying is that the last `console` statement  is the synchronous part, nothing in the event queue should be executed before it.

Comment: Do the events raised by `emitter.emit()` gets pushed to the eventsQueue in node ?

Comment: `nothing in the event queue should be executed before it` and it's what is happening. The console.log is executed before the events management. Maybe i'm not getting it, sorry :\

Comment: What do you mean by 'management' ? I mean that events handler is called before the console.log (isnt that the 'management' you are referring)

Comment: In order: `emitter.on` handler is registered in the node process memory, `emitter.emit` is considered async so will be executed after the execution of the current context, and last is executed the `console.log`. Is more clear? I mean, i don't see the problem: what is sync is execute before the async operation

Answer (score 0):

> Not all Callbacks in JS or Node JS Are asynchronous.

Example array sort ,map ,reduce etc.It is 
 clearly mentioned in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous) that the

> The EventEmitter calls all listeners synchronously in the order in
>   which they were registered.

So you get this behaviour.

Comment: Do the events raised by emitter.emit() gets pushed to the eventsQueue in node ?

Comment: Well yes if you are gonna use setImmediate or setInterval with them otheriwse they are just executed in the callstack ,without waiting in the eventqueue.

Comment: so these functions (setInterval etc) are the one that puts the event in the eventsQueue, and not all events go through it ?

Comment: The basic fundamental is that we have single-threaded event loop and we want to execute everything with that ,so anything like setInterval or setImmediate or any api call that takes time to process ,gets shifted to the event queue ,such that our call stack remains empty to execute the code which doesn't takes time. And when those process completes `event loop ` shifts them to call stack again and their callback gets executed. Moreover the call back is nothing but the  function which is called at the completion of a given task.

Comment: The description I mentioned here is just the basic overview ,there are web apis (in browsers ) and other libraries  which are partially out of scope here.